# How do I get the request body when authenticating?

Tags: servicestack

I need to use a JSON object as an authentication in Servicestack V.4.0.22. The object is in the body of an HTTP POST:

```js
{ "username":"santaclaus","password":"verysecret","customfield":"stuff" }
```

From what I have read from other similar questions the solution should be to create a custom authentication provider extending `CredentialsAuthProvider`, but somehow `IServiceBase` `authService` does not contain the original request input.

How do I access the original request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the original Request with:

```
authService.Request
```

The Request DTO with:

```
authService.Request.Dto
```

Or the underlying ASP.NET HttpRequest with:

```
var aspReq = (HttpRequestBase)authService.Request.OriginalRequest;
```

Comment: hmm i did try going through each field of the authService.Request, but the fields RawBody, FormData & the inputStream came up empty. The Dto  which got filled with the username & password but of course couldn´t get mapped with the customfield, the content length was correct, the headers correct. Its also running selfhost by the way

Comment: `FormData` is only populated for POST'ed form urlencoded variables (e.g. HTML Form Post not JSON). If you want to reread the Request InputStream you need to [buffer the Request Stream](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/release-notes.md#buffered-stream-option-has-now-added-to-response).

Comment: That did the trick, thank you. I'll look through the updates more thoroughly from now on.